# scrollbar in constraint layout not working

Tags: android, xml

I have tried the below code but it doesn't scroll when I rotate my application it will cover most of screen but I need to scroll there it doesn't working there. Is it right way to use scroll view in constraint layout. I have seen this type of example. There it was in working condition I have tried the below code but it doesn't scroll when I rotate my application it will cover most of screen but I need to scroll there it doesn't working there. Is it right way to use scroll view in constraint layout. I have seen this type of example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="611dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_bmi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/bmi" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bmr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/bmr" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ideal_weight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ideal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/water_intake"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/water" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/calorie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/calories" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nutrition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/nutrition" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this layer it might work.put appbarlayout inside ConstraintLayout layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--add your scrollview or nestedscrollview here-->


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ScrollView height is fixed to 611dp.

If you use a fixed size, then the content should be greater than 611dp to be able to scroll.

You should use

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ....>
```